# Smartsheet API Proxy Setup for Java

Tags: java, proxy, smartsheet-api

Is there a way to setup a proxy in the Smartsheet Java SDK? I think Im getting java.net.UnknownHostException: api.smartsheet.com due to our internal proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I don't have a specific code sample. There is an example of customizing the HTTP stack in our QR Code sample: https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/QRScanner