# No such host is known (api.smartsheet.com) - Java SDK

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

Trying to get sheet data using the smartsheet java sdk. This is the code I am using -

```
Smartsheet smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder()
                .setAccessToken(accessToken)
                .build();
smartsheet.setAssumedUser(emailAddress);
smartsheet.sheetResources().getSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null,null, null);
```

This is the error I am getting -

> java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known
> (api.smartsheet.com)

When I make a get request on postman using the same access token it works.

Comment: are you behind a proxy? where is the code running?

Comment: Running this code on IntelliJ

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340587/no-such-host-is-known-api-smartsheet-com-java

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Java, but based on a bit of research I'd suspect you may be getting that error due to your internal proxy. According to the (accepted) answer in [this other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163553/smartsheet-api-proxy-setup-for-java), you can setup a proxy in the Smartsheet Java SDK by using the same process that Smartsheet's [QR Code sample](https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/QRScanner) uses.

Comment: I tried using a proxy from this sample - https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-java-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md. When I do this I get an error saying 


com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with the structure/contents of your request. I'd suggest you post a new question to SO and include the code that's resulting in this error.